# TypeError when running regressions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, typeerror

I am new to Python and am using it to run regressions. I get the following error:

`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

when I try to create a subset of my data which contain Country names, continent (Asia, Americas, etc.), population, GDP per Capita, and Life Expectancy in years.

This is my code:

```
#makes the variables below numeric
pop = data.groupby('pop').size()    
life = data.groupby('lifeExp').size()
gdp = data.groupby('gdpPercap').size()

#create a subset within the data used here
sub1=data[(['pop']>= 100001)]
```

I get the error after I run the last line. My  pop variable (population) is a float variable, but I thought `pop = data.groupby('pop').size()` makes it numeric. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you may be using numpy or pandas. If so, please add the appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: Hi, yes, the first line of the program was importing pandas and numpy, so this line is using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

in `['pop'] >= 100001`, you are indeed comparing a list `['pop']` with an int `100001`. Make sure that you're referencing the data column properly, i.e. `data['pop'] >= 100001`

Comment: Lester, thank you a bunch, this worked, I changed the line to sub1=data[(data['pop']>= 100001)]

Answer (score 0):

In your comparison you are creating a list containing ['pop'] and comparing that to the int 100001. I am guessing you wanted to compare the int to the variable pop